# While creating dynamic android fragments, through fragment manager I am unable to setText on view of that fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

I am new  to android and is stuck in it for quite a while now. So far what I have detected through debugging is that my view is null and that's the reason that it cannot set value to my textView.

It works , perfectly fine :

```
articleFragment = new ArticleFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, articleFragment).commit();
// articleFragment.setText(selectedArticle);
```

but as soon as I remove comment from last line, it displays an error.

Following is the class of fragment:

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView view;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        view.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Update :

It's something with the view. On case of tablet view or landscape view, The view of this fragment is not null. But incase of mobile portrait mode , watch shows null. It is also important to mention that, I haven't used dynamic fragments for landscape and large layout. 
Following are portrait mode xml files :
Main.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
      xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools";
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" > 

     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
     android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

ArticleFragment.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <TextView   
   xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";     
   android:id="@+id/article" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="16dp" 
   android:textSize="18sp" android:text="Article Fragment" />
```

Update 2  :

Fragment.java

```
    package com.example.smd.fragments;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.view.View;


   public class Fragments extends Activity implements     
       TitleFragment.TitleFragmentListener
 {
private  boolean var;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var=false;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)  != null) {
    TitleFragment titleFragment= new TitleFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, titleFragment).commit();

     var=true;
    }
}

public void onTitleFragmentItemClick(String selectedArticle) {
    ArticleFragment articleFragment = (ArticleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article);
    if (var == false) {


        if (articleFragment != null)
            articleFragment.setText(selectedArticle);
    }
    else {
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            articleFragment = ArticleFragment.newInstance("hello world");
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, articleFragment).commit();

        }

    }


}
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        TitleFragment titleFragment= new TitleFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, titleFragment).commit();
       var=true;
    }

    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

ArticleFragment.java

```
  package com.example.smd.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;



 public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment
{
TextView view;
private CharSequence text;


public static ArticleFragment newInstance(CharSequence text) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putCharSequence("ArticleFragment", text); // Setup initial text.
    ArticleFragment f = new ArticleFragment();
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}


public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    final Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (icicle != null) {
        // Restore text after config change.
        this.text = icicle.getCharSequence("myText");
    } else if (args != null) {
        // Fragment created for the first time via factory method.
        this.text = args.getCharSequence("myText");
    }
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);

    onTextChanged();
    return view;
}


public void setText(String text){

    this.text =  text; // Store in field.
    if (view != null) {
        onTextChanged(); // Update view if it's inflated.
    }
}

private void onTextChanged() {
    view.setText(text);
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I am trying on phone directly :

It just shows that : Unfortunately Fragment has stopped . 

FRagment here is also name of my project

Comment: Use android studio to launch it and see the backtrace.

Comment: It's  something with the view. On case of tablet view or landscape view, The view of this fragment is not null. But incase of mobile portrait mode , watch shows null.



It is also important to mention that, I haven't used dynamic fragments for landscape and large layout.

Comment: Add `layout.article_view.xml` to your question so we can see more clearly why. And do you have `layout.article_view.xml` in different versions for say screen sizes, API levels, or the likes?

Comment: Yes, they have similar names   but all of them are placed in their respective directories.

Incase of article fragment of lanscape mode , all fragments are declared in xml . But in portrait mode , their is  1 frame layout instead .

 On start , I display 1 fragment, And on eventlistener, I   want it to replace fragment and show output on articleFragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing because at the time you're calling `setText` the fragment's view hierarchy has not been inflated yet - `view` is `null`. Here's a complete example:

#### ArticleFragment.java

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    // Fragment stores its own state...
    private CharSequence text;

    // ...and references to its views.
    TextView view;

    /** Your factory method for this fragment. Never use custom costructors with fragments! */
    public static ArticleFragment newInstance(CharSequence text) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putCharSequence("myText", text); // Setup initial text.
        ArticleFragment f = new ArticleFragment();
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (icicle != null) {
            // Restore text after config change.
            this.text = icicle.getCharSequence("myText"); 
        } else if (args != null) {
            // Fragment created for the first time via factory method.
            this.text = args.getCharSequence("myText");
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // This is only valid if R.layout.article_view is a TextView!
        view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
        onTextChanged(); // Update TextView with saved text if any.
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        this.view = null; // Avoid memory leaks. Clear references to any views.
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Persist fragment state - "text" - across config changes.
        outState.putCharSequence("myText", this.text); 
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        this.text = text; // Store in field.
        if (view != null) {
            onTextChanged(); // Update view if it's inflated.
        }
    }

    private void onTextChanged() {
        view.setText(text);
    }
}
```

#### CopyOfMainActivity.java

```
public class CopyOfMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // Hold reference to fragment so you can call setText later.
    private ArticleFragment articleFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Activity is freshly started, create new fragment, attach it.
            articleFragment = ArticleFragment.newInstance("Your article");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, articleFragment)
                .commit();
        } else {
            // After config change the fragment is already loaded. Find it.
            articleFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly , That is the cause . 

But even in this code , value of text and view remains null throughout.


I have adjusted the code according to my  working a bit . How can I show you modified one?

Through modified code after reviewing your example, their isn't any sort of error (Due to those if =null condition) but Don't know why value of text and view still remain null

Comment: @Mobeen 1) You changed the argument key in `newInstance` to `"ArticleFragment"` but `onCreate` is still expecting `"myText"`. 2) Couldn't have picked a more generic name than `var`. What is it supposed to do? 3) `findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)` is never null. It's the frame layout, it's always there, you just switch fragments inside it. 4) Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, that key , you mentioned in point 1 did the magic. I initially didnt had the idea that it was working that way. Secondly , fragment container will be null incase of landscape and large screens.(Just for clarity)

Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think fragment container can be null. Fragment manager will start throwing exceptions after you rotate the device and there's nowhere to put already attached fragments. Please verify.

Comment: Currently , I haven't handled change in orientation. But changing it , doesn't explicitly throws errors. It even works for both orientations

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment inflates `R.layout.article_view` which is most likely not a TextView, but a LinearLayout, FrameLayout or such.

Therefore, your R.layout.article_view should look as follow :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Once that's in place, your Fragment should do the following :

```
  public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView view;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    view = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    return (layout);
  }


    public void setText(String text) {
      if (view != null) {
        view.setText(text);
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I gave it  a try , but again , it showed similar error,

That's because view was null again in setText and I removed that null condition

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>



It is my main

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Article Fragment" />
and it is my article fragment

Comment: @Mobeen Can you put the layouts in your question and format it as code? Reading this makes my eyes bleed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check all your instances of `article_view.xml`, and put the `TextView` inside a `Layout` like `LinearLayout` and give it an `id` like `android:id="@+id/textView"`

Now get the `TextView` like:

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView textView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return view;
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Also, check if `textView` is `null`, and if it is use `Log.d()` to log the event.

Comment: textView is null .

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can do it in much simpler way:-

Your Article fragment

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
imimport android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARTICLE_NAME = "ArticleName";

    public ArticleFragment() {
    }

    public static ArticleFragment newInstance(String text) {
        ArticleFragment f = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putString(ARTICLE_NAME, text);
        f.setArguments(bun);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);

        // Set text directly
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView))
                .setText(null != getArguments() ? getArguments().getString(
                        ARTICLE_NAME, "") : "Invalid Article Name");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Your Main activity class

```
 import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public class CopyOfMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new ArticleFragment("Your article"))
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

Please note imports I have used.I am using android.support.V4.app.fragment to support older devices.

Comment: This will crash e.g. on screen rotation. Fragment has to have an empty constructor. It also means that the text will be lost after screen orientation because custom cosntructors are not called by framework.

Comment: Yeah thanks I realize that see the edit & why you down voted I was trying to help.

Comment: You kept the old fragment constructor in the activity. The fragment no longer has `setText` method. Avoid words like "simple" when your fragment class is at least twice as long as OP's. We all try to help and we all would much rather see a good quality answer than a cry for more points. Points are not helping.